# Deep linking with splash screen and login state

Tags: android, navigation, splash-screen, android-architecture-navigation

I use Navigation Component. 
I have app with 2 main parts: 
1 splash activity with it's nav_graph
2 main activity with bottom navigation where every menu item has its own nav_graph. 
The problem is that i cant figure out how to do navigation when notification pops up.

So when notification arrived and user clicked on it, i need: 
- check if app is open and what screen is open now
- if app is closed or in background, through deep link, check at splash activity: if user is logged in - move to main activity (if not provide auth screen) keep navigation on deep link to fragment I need.

Splash graph and one of three memu items graphs

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/splash_graph"
            app:startDestination="@id/splashFragment">

    <fragment android:id="@+id/splashFragment"
              android:name="com.app.app.ui.navigation.fragment.SplashFragment"
              android:label="SplashFragment">

        <action android:id="@+id/action_splashFragment_to_authFragment"
                app:popUpTo="@+id/authFragment"
                app:popUpToInclusive="true"
                app:destination="@id/authFragment"/>

        <action android:id="@+id/action_splashFragment_to_mainActivity"
                app:popUpTo="@+id/mainActivity"
                app:popUpToInclusive="true"
                app:destination="@id/mainActivity" app:launchSingleTop="true"/>
    </fragment>

    <fragment android:id="@+id/authFragment"
              android:name="com.app.app.ui.navigation.fragment.AuthFragment"
              android:label="AuthFragment">

        <action android:id="@+id/action_authFragment_to_mainActivity"
                app:popUpTo="@+id/mainActivity"
                app:popUpToInclusive="true"
                app:destination="@id/mainActivity" app:launchSingleTop="true"/>
    </fragment>

    <activity android:id="@+id/mainActivity"
              android:name="com.app.app.ui.navigation.activity.MainActivity"
              android:label="MainActivity">
        <deepLink android:id="@+id/deepLinkMain" app:uri="com.app.app/"/>
    </activity>


</navigation>
```

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/nextFragment"
            app:startDestination="@id/nxtFragment">

    <fragment android:id="@+id/nxtFragment"
              android:name="com.app.app.ui.navigation.fragment.NextFragment"
              android:label="Next">
        <deepLink
                android:id="@+id/deepLink"
                app:uri="com.app.app/nextFragment{id}"
                android:autoVerify="true"/>
        <argument
                android:name="id"
                app:argType="string"/>
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using pending intent, suppose you get data payload like below :

```
{
      "title":"Title",
      "message":"message test",
      "data":{
             "meta":{
                "notificationType":"1",
                 "name":"Rjz"
                    }
             }
}
```

and as per **notificationType** you have to open specific screen then you can do following :

**sendNotification("msg","title",remoteMessage.data)**

```
private fun sendNotification(messageBody: String,title: String?,data: MutableMap<String, String>) {

    val intent = Intent(this, SplashActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("meta", data["meta"])
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT
    )

    val channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id)
    val defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
    val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)

    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_app_logo)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentText(messageBody)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle())
        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

    val notificationManager =
        getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

    // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val channel = NotificationChannel(
            channelId,
            "Channel human readable title",
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        )
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build())
}
```

and in splash screen you can check that pending intent data , like this :

```
val metaString: String? = if (intent.hasExtra("meta")) {
                intent.extras.get("meta").toString()
            } else {
                null
            }
    var gson = Gson()   
    var pushData = gson.fromJson(
                    metaString,
                    YourModel::class.java
                )       
    if(pushData.notificationType==1){
    NavDeepLinkBuilder(this@SplashActivity)
            .setComponentName(MainActivity::class.java)
            .setGraph(R.navigation.name_of_nav_graph)
            .setDestination(R.id.your_dstination_fragment)
            .setArguments(bundleOf(
                         "name" to pushData.name)
                         ).createTaskStackBuilder().startActivities()
    }
```

You can also pass argument if you want to pass.

its an easy way to do in such cases.
let me know if you stuck anywhere.
enjoy..!!

Comment: This is straight forward. It takes the user to the Splash screen when the notification is clicked and from Splash screen, `TaskStackBuilder` takes the user to `MainActivity`.

Comment: Let's say if I want to stop the user at Login Screen and require to user to complete the login before taking to the MainActivity. How can I do that?

Comment: @SrikarReddy in that case you can store value or you can pass values using argument. once user login successfully you can redirect as per arguments.

Comment: The point of using `NavDeepLinkBuilder` is to avoid storing the values or passing them across Fragment Transactions and let the system take care of it.

Comment: Your code is a basic example of how to perform a Deep link. The use case is more complicated with destinations decided when the notification is tapped and the logged in state of the user.

Comment: Regarding the bounty, you are going to get it once the time expires.